# Can I have two properties with different names but same model types?

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller, properties, openweathermap

I was just wondering if this is allowed in writing clean code.

So I have a weather app with **HomeViewController** you can call it, that displays the **temperature**, **location** **name**, and **date** of users current location weather.

Then if I want to change the details of the **HomeViewController**, I tap on a UIButton that leads me to a List of Weathers for different location, call it the **WeatherListViewController**.

The **WeatherListViewController** has a UITableView displaying different weathers for different searched locations and holds it.

I can tap on any weather from that list and go back to **HomeViewController** to populate with the given information.

But, I am stuck on a problem. Inside **WeatherListViewController**, I need to have a default weather cell for users current location at all times. So I keep that at the first index of 0.
After that it's just whatever weather a user wants to search and add to the list.

So, let's say I tap other than the weather cell from my current location, and choose let's say a weather cell for Texas. And it populates the **HomeViewController**, which works. Then let's say I want to go back to my **WeatherListViewController** and add more, but the **default** **weather** **cell** for users current location is switched to **TexasWeatherCell** instead as the new index of 0.

So, I found a hack that works which is having two properties of the same model type but different names. **defaultWeather**, which holds weather information from users current location and the other, **currentWeather**, which displays different weather.

Is this feasible?

> This is inside my HomeViewController

```
private var currentWeather: CurrentWeather? {
    didSet {
        if let weather = currentWeather {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.setAttributes(forWeather: weather)
            }
        }
    }
}
private var defaultWeather: CurrentWeather?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse you can. Your model `CurrentWeather` is an abstract data type. I would recommend renaming it to simply `Weather` for readability. Then your code would be

```
private var currentWeather: Weather? {
didSet {
    if let weather = currentWeather {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.setAttributes(forWeather: weather)
        }
    }
}
}
private var defaultWeather: Weather?
```

Sound good?